# Azure app service - certificates only on certain paths

Tags: azure, iis, webforms, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Running IIS locally I would be able to add to my web.config on a per path basis config like the following:

```
<location path="something.asmx">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="true" manyToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="false">
                    <oneToOneMappings>
                        <clear />
                        <add userName="" password="" certificate="#Thumbprint value from cert in loaded into the app service#" />
                    </oneToOneMappings>
                    <manyToOneMappings>
                        <clear />
                    </manyToOneMappings>
                </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
            </authentication>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

But I get a HTTP 500 error with the error code 0x8007005

Should it be possible to to do this within the app service? I don't really want to use the following options:
[image]

Because most of my site is access via front door using another authentication method, I'm just trying to make one file accessible via certificate authentication.

Comment: It might sound like Azure App Service (Windows) is on IIS, but there are fundamental differences, so you cannot expect everything (1:1 mapping) works the same way.

Comment: understood - but can the same behaviour be achieved somehow or is this just something unsupported on the app service?

Comment: If you select the `Allow` -  `Client certificate mode`, it enables the authentication with both client certificate and Authentication Token.
If you provide client certificate it will accept and if certificate is not provided the request is processed by enabling authentication with Authentication Token.

Comment: Client certificates allow applications to request certificates for incoming requests. Only clients with valid certificates can access the application. If incoming client certificates are enabled, only authenticated clients with valid certificates can access the application.